# Facebook authorization using OAuth 2.0 PHP not working in ie and safari

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I m developed a app for a photo contest.

steps:

1. the user authorize the app where i get the permission to get the photos and email.
2. Intro page and choose from facebook link
3. Photo's page where all of the users facebook photos are shown to choose. the user select one photo and click next
4. form to fill in and submit.
5. thankyou page with the photo selected.

In this app, my canvas url is "http://mysite.com/index.php?" where i authorize the app.

so when the user click "choose from facebook" link it redirects to another page where i display the photos.

In this page(photos.php) i use the below code same as in the index.php,

```
require 'src/config_app.php';
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appid,
  'secret' => $appsecret,
  'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

but i get the fatal error as below :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in  var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/src/base_facebook.php on line 1107
```

This happens only in ie and safari, i checked my chrome and firefox which is good.

I almost finished my app with using chrome and now stuck with this major issue in other browsers.

Am i doing anything wrong !?

Kindly help.

Many thanks.

Comment: My api code has been working for months, but suddenly the /me/posts bit stopped working. Even the graph API test page does not work! developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/…